# how to format struts-dojo datetimepicker to show 24 hours instead of 12 hours?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, dojo, datetimepicker

Here is my `datetimepicker`.

```
<sx:datetimepicker id="strtTP" type="time" name="fromTime"  />
```

I tried  setting the format in onload javascript. but didnt work.

```
var strtTime = dojo.widget.byId('strtTP');

strtTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

strtTime.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
```

Can anyone help me to display `datetimepicker` in 24 hour format?

Comment: This should work for normal datetime picker `format: 'HH:mm',
        pickDate: false,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: false           `

Comment: thanks, bt it doesnt work for struts_dojo datetimepicker :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/datetimepicker.html), it should be

```
<sx:datetimepicker id = "strtTP" 
                 type = "time" 
                 name = "fromTime"  
        displayFormat = "HH:mm" />
```

Comment: but that doesnt make any change